# Format SQL Script in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, format, sql-server-data-tools

Normally we can format code or markup in visual studio with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> shortkeys.

How we can format SQL script code like stored procedures or views or other things using shortkeys?

Note: I am using SSDT with VS2012, where I can edit scripts of a database, but I can't find format option.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a built-in SQL Format option for SSDT. You can use a plug-in such as Red-Gate's SQL Prompt to get that functionality, but I don't think there's a native option for formatting SQL at this time.